# Как правильно запарсить данные в <script> элементе из JavaScript объекта используя bs4 ResultSet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Используя следующую строку я получаю ResultSet:

```
abc = soup.findAll('script', text = re.compile('Data'))
```

Сам получаемый ResultSet:

```
[<script type="text/javascript">
data = {"url":"haha.com", "id":"12345", "name":"haha",};
... function() {abc.devg....})'
...
```

Из всего этого цель извлечь параметры в data, а именно допустим значения url и id.
Как это сделать идей нет. Пробовал различные варианты парсинга с помощью супа и то что приведено выше - самый близкий к нужному вариант.

Comment: beautifulsoup4 тут не причём (эта библиотека понимает html, xml. но не понимает javascript). Чтобы достать url, id из javascript объекта, вам нужна библиотека, которая понимает javascript. См. [How to extract a JSON object that was defined in a HTML page javascript block using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13323976/4279)

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле `BeautifulSoup` здесь причём - с его помощью Вы можете найти нужный `script` элемент в HTML дереве. Вот уже после того, как элемент найден и его текст на руках, Вам нужно будет решить, каким образом пропарсить JS код и вытащить значение нужной переменной.

Один, достаточно практичный и простой, вариант, это регулярное выражение. Причём, Вы можете использовать одно и тоже скомпилированное регулярное выражение для нахождения элемента, и для получения `data` объекта в виде строки, которую мы можете пропустить через [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), чтобы получить питоновскую структуру данных (в данном примере ниже - словарь).

Рабочий пример:

```
import json
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            data = {"url":" haha.com", "id": "12345", "name": "haha"};
            function() { // something here });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

pattern = re.compile(r"data = (\{.*?\});$", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

if script:
    obj = pattern.search(script.text).group(1)
    obj = json.loads(obj)
    print(obj)
```

На выходе получите:

```
{'url': ' haha.com', 'id': '12345', 'name': 'haha'}
```

Также смотрите вот этой StackOverflow post, где разобрана похожая задача - помимо регулярных выражений, там есть пример использования JS парсера [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit):

- [Extracting text using BeautifulSoup in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111752/extracting-text-using-beautifulsoup-in-python)